# Can't use eager execution in Tensorflow 1.5 on windows7 machine

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-7-x64

### **Problem**

> cant use eager execution in tensorflow version 1.5

### **code**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import timeline

tf.enable_eager_execution()

x = tf.random_normal([0,10000])
y= tf.random_normal([10000,1000])

res = tf.matmul(x, y)

# Run the graph with full trace option
with tf.Session() as sess:
    run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
    run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
    sess.run(res, options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)

    # Create the Timeline object, and write it to a json
    tl = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
    ctf = tl.generate_chrome_trace_format()
    with open('timeline.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(ctf)
```

### **Stack Trace**

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
>     from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:/Users/hello/PycharmProjects/crimeBuster/main.py", line 6, in 
>       tf.enable_eager_execution()
>   AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'enable_eager_execution'

### **Version**

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
# 1.5.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back in [version 1.5](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/g3doc/guide.md), eager execution was still in the contributed packages, so you need to import it explicitly; the correct usage is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
tfe.enable_eager_execution()
```

Also, just keep in mind that:

> For eager execution, we recommend using TensorFlow version 1.8 or newer.

(from the [Github page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager))

Version 1.7 was the first where the command `tf.enable_eager_execution()` was made available, i.e. eager execution was moved out of `contrib` (see [v1.7 changes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.7.0)).

Comment: Thanx for the reply, But my machine dose't support avx instructions so I am unable to install that version.